# globally renaming every node in XML document

Tags: xml, xslt, rename

I want to globally rename every node in an XML element by appending the existing name with a suffix.

The current XSLT I wrote below works, but loses element values.  How do I keep the values?

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:variable name="suffix" select="'_Ver1'"/>
<xsl:template match="node()">
    <xsl:element name="{concat(local-name(.), $suffix)}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because `node()` also includes text nodes. If your input XML had any line-breaks, you may have noticed elements like `<_Ver1/>` in your output.

Try something like this instead:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:variable name="suffix" select="'_Ver1'"/>

  <xsl:template match="text()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{concat(name(.),$suffix)}">
      <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I've added a template for `text()` and also a `copy-of` for any attributes that might be in the XML.

Answer (score 1):

The node test `node()` matches *any type of node* (including, but not limited to, element nodes). The following stylesheet implements the standard **identity transform for all non-element nodes**, with an **additional template for renaming elements**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:variable name="suffix" select="'_Ver1'"/>
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()[not(self::*)]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:element name="{concat(local-name(.), $suffix)}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Test input:

```
<root>
    <test1 attr="t">test</test1>
    <test1>testing</test1>
    <test1>tested</test1>
    <test1>tester</test1>
</root>
```

Output:

```
<root_Ver1>
    <test1_Ver1 attr="t">test</test1_Ver1>
    <test1_Ver1>testing</test1_Ver1>
    <test1_Ver1>tested</test1_Ver1>
    <test1_Ver1>tester</test1_Ver1>
</root_Ver1>
```

Comment: This looks equally workable.  Will keep this in my back pocket.

Comment: +1 for a good answer. Just a note: The second template isn't only "additional" -- it is more important that it is *overriding* the identity rule.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `|text()` to the expression?